# Задать вес для элемента в android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Tags: java, android

В обычном GridLayote можно это сделать так: `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`
А как это сделать если используется библиотека поддержки и API 15

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/test_xiaomi6"
                android:contentDescription="Смарфтон"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>



        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="2"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBrand"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Бренд:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBrand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Бренд:"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAlternativeName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Альтернативное имя:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAlternativeName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Имя" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRepresented"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Представлено:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRepresented"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Представлено:" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Состояние:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Дата"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Цены в магазинах"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPricies"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При указании android:layout_columnWeight="1" для 1 TextView элемент исчезает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы задали элементу вес, а соседнему `math_parent` - естественно `math_parent` отберёт всё пространство себе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `app:layout_columnWeight="1"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    ...
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Так же можно использовать `app:layout_columnSpan="..."`

Comment: Элементы становятся невидимыми

Comment: добавьте скрин в вопрос? возможно вес других элементов не выставлен/выставлен неправильно

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: невидимыми становятся элементы, которые внизу и выходят за край экрана? Судя по вашей реализации вам лучше использовать `RecyclerView` или, как заплатку, завернуть `GridLayout` в `ScrollView`

Comment: Ниже GridLayout еще неходится RecyclerView, и все это находится в ScrollView, добавил полностью код

Comment: ну понятно, а какие элементы то невидимы?) поясните, в чем сложность. На начальный вопрос, как он был задан, ответ есть. Пример работает корректно.

Comment: Textview становится не видимыми, где указывается android:layout_columnWeight="1"

Comment: -_- а если указать, как в моем ответе - `app:layout_columnWeight="1"`?

Comment: опечатался, именно при указании вашей строчки объект становится невидимым

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79259/discussion-between-jarvis-j-and-danilshik).

Comment: при моем, он пишет, что у v7 нет такого параметра